# whether i get charged for not terminating the EMR cluster

Tags: amazon-web-services, apache-spark, amazon-ec2, amazon-emr

I have start/stop in EC2 Instance in order to stop the EMR(Elastic Map Reduce) in AWS. But, After stopping the EC2 Instance, Whether i get charged because of cluster running on EMR?

If yes or No, Please explain why?

Comment: You can't stop EMR cluster. So its not clear what you are actually doing.

Comment: Whether i need to pay, after Stopping EC2 instance in AWS?

Comment: Yes, you pay for storing the instance in the stopped state.